# Create unique postalcode and country generator

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, list

I am working an C# application where I have to add test employee data to a MongoDB collection.

There is a working connection already and some predefined list where the program is going to loop through to insert data. However, I am stuck add the point where I'd have to add an address.

I need a piece of code to create **at least 10.000 unique postalcodes** without using a library if possible.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Bson;


namespace Application
{
    class Program
    {
        public class Employee
        {
            public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Age { get; set; }
            public string Street { get; set; }
            public string Country { get; set; }
            public string Postalcode { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MongoClient client = new MongoClient();
            var server = client.GetServer();
            var db = server.GetDatabase("testdb");
            var collection = db.GetCollection<Employee>("testcollection");

            List<string> names = new List<string>()
            {
                "John Smith",
                "Matthew Williams",
                "David Harris",
                "Christopher Martin",
                "Paul Shark"
            };

            Random random = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                int nameIndex    = random.Next(0, 5);
                int projectIndex = random.Next(0, 3);  
                int ageIndex     = random.Next(18, 67);

                string nameValue = names[nameIndex];

                Employee employee = new Employee
                {
                    BSN      = "BSN" + i,
                    Name     = nameValue,
                    Age      = ageIndex
                };

                collection.Save(employee); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried to use the code on this other page: stackoverflow.com/questions/1344221/… However, it only creates postalcodes. It won't guarantee if the postalcode is actually unique.. so it isn't what I am looking for. I need to create 10.000 unique postalcodes. If all postalcodes are 100% unique, then the combination of country / postalcode is always unique as well. - edited post

Answer (score 0):

When I test forms I grab Faker.net from Nuget. This will generate random data for everything you need.

The implementation is pretty simple. Going from memory here so your mileage may vary but you get the idea.

var address1 = Faker.address.address1;

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not pretty sure this would help me out. I need a piece of code where I can generate at least 10.000 unique postalcode/country-combinations. So if Ican create 10.000 unique postalcodes it's enough :)

Comment: I use it for selenium automation to create randomized data. It should work just fine.